# How can I merge a partition with unallocated space? (In Ubuntu)

Tags: partitioning, disk-management, ubuntu-20.04

I'm stuck as to how I can fully utilize all my free space. I have 1TB of storage. A few months ago, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 into it. Then something happened (my fault really) and Ubuntu stopped working. I loaded another Ubuntu version, but I kept the older one because I had some files I couldn't afford to delete. So I have a new Ubuntu now (this is what I'm using) and an older one. I'll just call these as OS1 (old ubuntu) and OS2 (new ubuntu). OS2 is what I'm using and I'm currently running out of space on that. I only have about 40-50GB left. I recently just deleted OS1 because it's been completely inaccessible, and now I have a huge block of unallocated space.

What I'm stuck with is I don't know how I can combine the OS2 partition with the free space. If anyone can give a step by step detail, I'll be really grateful.

For reference, this is what my disk looks like. Please anyone kindly help. I'm not that good with Ubuntu and I'd really like some help. Please and thank you.

[image: Screenshot from GNOME Disks showing a large extended partition containing a block of empty space, followed by a partition]

Comment: You can also just not merge/resize partitions, create a filesystem in that free space and mount it on your existing system. Actually it's usually recommended to use more than one partition in a Linux system

Comment: @golimar So if I do this what happens once I use up that 40-50gb too? I'm sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: You can change the path configuration of your programs so they store things on the new partition, e.g. at /newpartition/Downloads instead of /home/user1/Downloads. If that's not possible you will have to mount the new partition onto the existing folder, e.g. `mount /dev/newpartition /home/user1/Downloads`. This second option may be more complicated than merge/resize

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resize the partition no problem.

**Make sure your backups are up to date.** This procedure can render your system unusable if it's interrupted or an error happens. Ideally, create a disk image with Clonezilla or similar software.

You'll have to carry this out using a system booted from USB (or DVD), because the partition will have to be moved left and that can't be done while the system is running off of it. Ubuntu installation USB will work just fine. It comes with GParted preinstalled. It's quite intuitive. Just don't forget to click the "Apply" button.

This operation will take a while - especially if it's a HDD that you'll be working on, rather than SSD.